# How should I pluralise “as is”?

Tags: grammatical-number, idioms

Let’s say I write: “*Just send me those documents **as is***”. Is that correct? Should the "as is" idiom be pluralised into “***as are***”, which sounds so wrong to me? Or are they both incorrect, in which case I may write “***as they are***”?

Comment: The only strange thing about your sentence is that if you're saying "these" documents, it sounds like you already have them, so why do they need to send them to you? :)

Comment: @Benjol indeed, “those documents” would be better. Thanks!

Comment: Just leave it "as is".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Merriam Webster's Dictionary of English Usage](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see page 131) says that the phrase *as is* is always singular, regardless of the number of items. *As are* is incorrect, but there is nothing wrong with using *as they are*. I think *as is* is most commonly used to do with the sale of something. ("I bought a used car, as is.")

Answer (score -1):

"As is" can be used in comparison, for example, "a tiger is a type of cat, as is a lion." You can also pluralize it, to expand on the previous example,  "tigers are cats, as are lions."

Comment: That is not the same "as is". "As is" in this context is an idiom, a contracted form of "as it is".  This "as is" cannot be replaced with "as are", because "as are" is not an accepted idiom. For instance you cannot say that you are selling two cars, "as are".